# jax-ws client example http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?op=VerifyEmail

Tags: jax-ws

I am having a hard time figuring out how to use [this](http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?op=VerifyEmail) web service using wsimport?

When I look at wsimport from http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/ it should be straight forward using the port object but it seems I am missing some basic knowledge about jax-ws?

EDIT:
Never mind I figured it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://ws.cdyne.com/", "EmailVerNoTestEmail");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        EmailVerNoTestEmailSoap port = service.getPort(EmailVerNoTestEmailSoap.class);
        System.out.println(port.verifyEmail("example@gmail.com", "123").getResponseText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```